# Converting a numeric value to a currency value in R

Tags: r

I have a project value column in a table titled df.table. It has [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RAte.png)several values e.g 10000000, 400000000. I'll like to convert that project value column into A$M(Australian Million) but don't want A$M to appear as a prefix to each value. I just want it as a label attached to the column name. How do I go about this please? Thank you.

Comment: There's no "currency" data type in R, so you will need to specify where exactly you want this to appear.

Comment: Are you simply looking to rename the column?

Comment: You can rename the column whatever you want. `names(data)[4] <- "Project.Value(A$M)"`. However, do note that using special characters like `(` and `$` in column names can make them harder to work with - after this rename you'll need to always quote the column name, either in backticks (if it would have been unquoted) or in regular quotes. If you want this rename for a graph or table label, it's usually easier to adjust the label in the output than it is to rename the column of the data.

Comment: Thanks all. I’m looking to apply a function to that column that reduces the values say from 40000000 to 40 because I have converted each value in the column to A$M. At present, the column is of numeric type.